# How to know the end of scrolling event for a <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I need to trigger a function if scroll end has reached for a div tag ..

```
    $("#page").bind("scroll",function(e){ //page is the ID of the div im scrolling
          if (document.body.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop()  <= $(this).height())
          {
             //the code here is called every time the scroll is happened i want to call     
             //this only when the scroll reaches the end of div
          }   
    });
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$("#page").scroll( function() {
  if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight()) {
   // what you want to do ...
  }
});
```

Comment: +1, even though I had to tweak it a little `$(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).outerHeight() - 10` ... now works to me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#page").bind("scroll",function(e){ //page is the ID of the div im scrolling

      if ( ( $(this).height() + $(this).scrollTop() ) => $(this).innerHeight() )
      {
         //Test it first without padding. Then see if you need to tweak the left part of the condition
      }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me

```
$("#page").scroll( function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).outerHeight())) 
    {
        alert("End here");
    }
});
```