# Some Jquery / CSS help regarding navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently working on my pfolio website and im quite far but not there yet...

http://thinkagain.nu/?page_id=2501 See this page I have this navigation bullets / dots on the right which you can navigate through the projects. I got it working for so far that if you click a bullet / dot it becomes selected (orange color) but what I want is that it also becomes selected state when you scroll down the sections, so without clicking on it.

So when your scrolling the 2nd project, the 2nd bullet / dot becomes selected, 3rd project makes the 3rd bullet / dot become selected and so on.

This is my code:

CSS:

```
#floatnav {
    position: fixed;
    right: -50px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 8em;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
}

.bullit {
    background-color:#242424;
    -moz-border-radius:17px;
    -webkit-border-radius:17px;
    border-radius:17px;
    border:0px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 9px -6px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888888; 
}
.bullit:hover {
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 9px -6px;
}
.bullit.active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    background:orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="floatnav">
    <a href="#cinerama" class="bullit"></a>
    <a href="#magicalgems" class="bullit"></a>
    <a href="#deltalloyd" class="bullit"></a>
    <a href="#ezchef" class="bullit"></a>
</ul>
```

Jquery/javascript:

```
$('#floatnav a').click(function() {
    $('#floatnav a').removeClass('active'); /*Remove previous*/
    $(this).addClass('active');             /*Active clicked*/
})
```

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Nick

Comment: What have you tried? *Hint:* You need to use something like `scrollTop` and `window.innerHeight`

Comment: My Java skills are not worth speaking about, I've tried looking up for tutorials but with no success. I already find it quite extraordinary that a designer like me came up with that much code already.. :P Where do I apply those lines? Thx

Comment: `Java != Javascript`. What you're using is jQuery, a library of Javascript. Use the hint I gave you to see if you can come up with it yourself, we're not going to just give it to you. I'm surprised you got an answer to the question you asked yesterday given you didn't show what you've tried. If you think it's too much work then you shouldn't be coding your own website in the first place IMHO

Comment: Alright Jedi Master! Imma give it a go thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (see example http://jsfiddle.net/shtrih/Z3BTd/)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var positions = [],
        elements = [],
        scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop()
    ;
    $('> div', '#main').each(function() {
         var pos = Math.abs($(this).position().top - scrolltop);
         positions.push(pos);
         elements[ pos ] = this.id;
    });

    var array_min = Math.min.apply(null, positions);
    var current_element_id = elements[ array_min ];
    console.log(current_element_id);

    $('a', '#floatnav').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="#'+ current_element_id +'"]', '#floatnav').addClass('active');
});
```

Used materials:

- [JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)
- [How to know the end of scrolling event for a <div> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244841/how-to-know-the-end-of-scrolling-event-for-a-div-tag)
- http://jqapi.com/

Comment: I suppose I should have asked instead, "Why not override the other ones instead?"

Comment: Thanks I acquired my goal using this code with some adjustments! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I hope it will help you understand and use on your website:

http://jsfiddle.net/dragulceo/KMnmb/1/

Notice that I included an external link to a jQuery plugin - [jQuery throttle / debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce)

You need to register a scroll handler and because the scroll handler is triggered many times you should use throttle method so that you don't affect the scrolling speed (avoid hiccups).

```
onScrollCallback = $.throttle(250, function () {
    var el;
    floatNavs.find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    el = getVisibleElement();
    if(el) {
        floatNavs.find('a[href="#' + $(el).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
});
$(document).on('scroll', onScrollCallback);
```

So now the browser triggers scroll event the code - moderately - will check to see which div is on screen and then add the `active` class for the `a` element that has the target the same with the `id` attribute.

The function that finds the element on screen is this one:

```
//gets the div on screen
getVisibleElement = function () {
    var scrl = window.scrollY,
        height = jQuery(window).height(),
        elHeight,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i< numberEls; i++) {
        item = $(targetEls[i]);
        pos = item.position();
        elHeight = item.height();
        // the criteria if the element is on screen is that 
        // the topX position is greater then the scrolled pixels 
        // minus half of the element. There can be variations 
        // depending on the scrolled items
        if (pos.top > scrl - elHeight / 2) {
            return targetEls[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And as you can see in the comments you can play with or change the condition that determines when the element is on screen depending on the height of the scrolled elements.

Comment: Thx for this, this is exactly what I want. I tried to implement it on my website, but it turns out quite wrong. Maybe it has to do with the fact its wordpress site / theme ? Anyways thanks a lot i'm gonna try and play around some more to see if I can get this baby to work! :)

Comment: If you just copy the js code and add it where you have your previous code and then go to wordpress admin -> appearance -> editor, select the base.php file and add at the bottom above the `</body>` tag the following: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>` it should work.